# To write with Java, where can i find the H.323 message protocol details? For IP to IP communication

Tags: java, linux, voip, fedora, h.323

I am trying to write from the scratch for learning H.323 (without any gatekeeper, straight peer-to-peer).

```
   public DatagramChannel rtp = null;
   public DatagramSocket socket = null;
```

But i am not sure which specification i should follow? there are lot of H.323 specs.
Has anyone wrote H.323 simple point-to-point apps? Can you suggest which documentation is good to get started for this?

e.g (alas its only SIP, which i tested): http://www.tech-invite.com/Ti-abnf-sdp.html

Thanks

References:

[image]

A simple Q.931 message exchange might go as follows:
[image]

http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures  (search h323 raw packets)

http://www.en.voipforo.com/H323/H323_example.php

http://xtapi.sourceforge.net/

http://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/Telecom/h323_call_flow.pdf

http://www.ccie-wiki.com/H323_Call_Processing.htm

Comment: Have you tried the [H.323](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.323) Wikipedia page? it even links to tutorials and information about implementing the protocol

Comment: "There are a lot of H.323 specs" — no, there aren't. There's exactly one, and it's ITU-T Recommendation H.323.

Comment: H.323 is big. And far from simple. You need the specs, available from ITU. At least : [H.323](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.323-200912-I/en). [H.225](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.225.0-200912-I/en) and [H.245](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.245/en) , These will refer you to other relevant specs - you'll at least need to know about ASN.1 and PER encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simple:
- take two ready made h.323 endpoints, 
- record the traffic with wireshark.
- Look for unclear points in h.323 standards
- Mimic the communication

test your endpoints for compatibility

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the RTP (Real time Protocol) protocol in your application in java, i suggest you to find an implementation like this one : http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/teaching/ais/1998/projects/java_rtp/report.html

It will be easier for you to begin

Comment: i mean something like this (exact message details, send/receive packet switchings) e.g: http://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/Telecom/h323_call_flow.pdf

Comment: Hi, what is your objective exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The definitive source are the ITU specs, but they are pretty hard to read. I would reccommend ["IP Telephony: Deploying VoIP Protocols and IMS Infrastructure"](http://www.ean-search.org/perl/ean-info.pl?ean=9780470665848) by Olivier Hersent as a very good start to learn the protocol.